# Positive definiteness and inverse of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-distributions

Let $L_{\boldsymbol{\Delta}}\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be the following symmetric matrix:

$L_{\boldsymbol{\Delta}} = \boldsymbol{\Delta} - \frac{1}{\operatorname{tr}(\boldsymbol{\Delta})} \boldsymbol{\Delta} \boldsymbol{1}_n  \boldsymbol{1}_n^\top \boldsymbol{\Delta} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, where $\boldsymbol{\Delta} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a diagonal matrix of strictly positive entries and $\boldsymbol{1}_n = [1, \ldots, 1]^\top \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

I have three questions:

1. Can we show that $L_{\boldsymbol{\Delta}}$ is (semi)positive definite?
2. Is there any change we can get a simple expression for its inverse?
3. This matrix is not a projector but involves projection onto a certain subspace and rescaling. Is there a certain way of writing $L_{\boldsymbol{\Delta}}$ to highlight this?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand\De\Delta\newcommand\de\delta\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$Let us assume that "diagonal matrix of strictly positive matrix" means "diagonal matrix with strictly positive diagonal entries".

Then the matrix $L:=L_\De$ is indeed positive semidefinite, but it does not have an inverse. Indeed, the $ij$-entry of $L$ is
$$L_{ij}=1(i=j)\de_i-\frac{\de_i\de_j}{\sum_1^n\de_k},$$
where the $\de_i$'s are the strictly positive diagonal entries of the matrix $\De$. Then for $x=[x_1,\dots,x_n]^\top\in\R^n$
$$x^\top Lx=\sum_1^n\de_i x_i^2
-\frac 1{\sum_1^n\de_k}\,\Big(\sum_1^n\de_i x_i\Big)^2\ge0$$
by a Cauchy--Schwarz inequality.

However, $x^\top Lx=0$ if $x_i=1$ for all $i$. So, $L$ is not invertible.

This answers your first two questions. As for your question 3, two things should be said about it: (i) the question is unclear and (ii) one should not ask multiple questions in one post on MathOverflow.